# Understanding the geometry of vector addition

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I want to construct, geometrically, the linear combination of vectors
$$(2,-1) + 2(-1,2).$$
The answer is, surely, $(0,3)$ by component-wise addition, but I'm trying to understand how the parallelogram comes into play. By brute-force with graphing software, I was able to plot the translated vectors producing the parallelogram and the the diagonal, giving the vector $(0,3)$. But how would I find these translated vectors in closed-form? The approach of simple "eye-balling it" doesn't seem sufficiently rigorous to me.

Comment: That "*translated vector*" is not the same kind of vector as the ones you are adding. You could lookup position vectors vs. displacement vectors, or vector spaces vs. affine spaces. Or just add the coordinates pairwise "by definition", depending on what the context of the question is.

Comment: If we view vectors as arrows going from one point to another in the plane, when you translate a vector in the $x$ direction you're simply adding the same number to the $x$ coordinate of the start and end point, same in the $y$. So to move a vector to form the other side of the parallelogram is the same as adding components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see from the graphic that

- one translated vector (dashed line) is generated by adding the position vector $(-2,4)$ to $(2,-1)$ resulting in $(2,-1)+(-2,4)=\color{blue}{(0,3)}$, resp.
- the other translated vector is generated by adding the position vector $(2,-1)$ to $(-2,4)$ resulting in $(-2,4)+(2,-1)=\color{blue}{(0,3)}$.

[image]

Observe that one dashed line is parallel to the vector $2(-1,2)=(-2,4)$.

- In fact it is the position vector $(-2,4)$ with start point added at $(2,-1)$ and end point in $(0,3)$. We can so use the dashed line by doing a *walk* from $(0,0)$ to $(0,3)$. We start in $(0,0)$ go from $(0,0)$ to $(2,-1)$ and now we walk along the dashed line from $(2,-1)$ *append* the vector $(-2,4)$ and end in $(0,3)$.
- We can also walk from $(0,0)$ to $(0,3)$ the other way round by starting in $(0,0)$ going from $(0,0)$ to $2(-1,2)=(-2,4)$ and now by walking the other dashed line from $(-2,4)$ to $(0,3)$ by appending the other vector $(2,-1)$.

Algebraically these two walks are described by using the rules of commutativity
\begin{align*}
(2,-1)+(-2,4)=\color{blue}{(0,3)}=(-2,4)+(2,-1)
\end{align*}
as indicated by the red colored vector identities in the graphic.

Comment: The diagram is very helpful, but I'm a bit confused. $(0,3)$ is surely the sum of the two vectors $(-2,4)$ and $(2,-1)$, but not the dashed lines themselves, right? I'm most interested in finding some way to characterized the dashed lines.

Comment: @JeremyS: I've added some info which might be helpful.